# Weighted average cost of short-term stock trading

Tags: julia, stock, trading, weighted-average

I'm new to programming and trying to learn Julia.  I tried to compute the weighted average cost of short-term stock trading activities as I did before in R. I rewrite the code in Julia, unfortunately, it return the incorrect result in data frame format.
I tried to investigate the result of each iteration step by changing `return vwavg` to `println([volume[i], s, unitprice[i], value[i], t, vwavg[i], u])` and the output is correct. is it a problem with rounding?
Really appreciate your help

```
# create trial dataset
df = DataFrame(qty = [3, 2, 2, -7, 4, 4, -3,-2, 4, 4, -2, -3],
                price = [100.0, 99.0, 101.0, 103.0, 95.0, 93.0, 90.0, 90.0, 93.0, 95.0, 93.0, 92.0])
# create function for weighted average cost of stock price
function vwacost(volume, unitprice)
    value = Vector{Float64}(undef, length(volume))
    vwavg = Vector{Float64}(undef, length(volume))
    for i in 1:length(volume)
        s = 0
        t = 0
        u = 0
        if volume[i]>0
            value[i] = (volume[i]*unitprice[i]) + t
            volume[i] = volume[i] + s
            vwavg[i] = value[i]/volume[i]
            u = vwavg[i]
            s = volume[i]
            t = value[i]
        else
            volume[i] = volume[i] + s
            value[i] = u * volume[i]
            s = volume[i]
            t = value[i]
            vwavg[i] = u
        end
    return vwavg
    end
end

out = transform(df, [:qty, :price] => vwacost)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple error:

```
    for i in 1:length(volume)
        ...
    return vwavg
    end
```

should be:

```
    for i in 1:length(volume)
        ...
    end
    return vwavg
```

You are currently returning the result after the first loop iteration, which is why your resulting `vwawg` vector has only one (the first) calculated entry, with all other entries being zero/whatever was in memory when you created the `vwawg` vector in the first place.

Comment: My bad, thank you, especially for a detailed explanation. Unexpectedly, the function is only correct for the first run, I try different syntax using `select()` or `transform()`, and the error is persisted. After some inspection, I figure out that the function replaces the "qty" column of the original df every time I apply the function. I test the equivalent function on R again, it returns the correct result no matter how much I applied the function to the same df

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the second problem of changing original df that result in incorrect result can be solved by `copy(df)`:

```
out = select(copy(df), [:qty, :price] => vwacost => :avgcost)
```

thus, the original df will not change and the result will consistent over time.